# I am trying to show the notification in laravel using socket.io

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io, laravel-8

I am  trying to  show the  notification  in laravel using socket.io server.js file

```
const server = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.io server listening on port ${port}`);
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");

  // Emit the custom event 'notificationData' with dynamic data
  socket.on('notificationData', (data) => {
    const notificationData = {
      message: data,
      // Add more dynamic data properties as needed
    };
    socket.emit('notificationData', notificationData);
  });

  // Handle disconnect event
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
  });
});
```

this script i  put  in blade  file just need show message under conole

```
 <script>
        const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Connected to Socket.io server');
        });

        // Request notification data from the server
        socket.emit('notificationData', 'Hello, world!');

        socket.on('notificationData', (data) => {
            const notificationData = data.message;
            console.log('Received notification data:', notificationData);
            // Handle the dynamic notification data here
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('Disconnected from Socket.io server');
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#license_held_image_input').change(function(e) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $('#preview_image').attr('src', event.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and this is  my  event file

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
class Notifications
{
use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

```
public $message;

public function \__construct($message)
{
    $this-\>message = $message;
}
```

}

I need  Get the  dynamic  data store  in $message How  this is  possible